# Sending thousands of email to employees (Exchange)

Tags: email, exchange

A monthly report for each employee will be generated by a company application, now we are adding some code to also email the report once generated. Each report is different so we need to send each report in a different email.

Is it better to push the whole thing to Exchange server in a loop and let it manage the load? is there some sort of the flag to tell the Exchange server that this message is of low priority or something like that? or should we make a queue of some sort to manage that and this queue should send `n` emails every few minutes or so? any best practice or tips?

Comment: To reduce load you could store the reports on an internal web server and email a link to the report.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably over thinking it.  Just send the emails.

Assuming the program's loop generates report 1, then emails it to person1, then generates report 2, emails to person 2, etc...the report generating phase will probably be long enough that you don't cause too much load on the exchange server.  Even a small exchange server should have no problem handling a few emails per second.

If there is a problem, you'll notice it by monitoring the exchange server while generating the reports.  Are it's CPUs pegged?  Is it getting sluggish?  Is the disk queue skyrocketing?  If so, add a small delay between emails.

Answer (score 4):

Not knowing the volume of your existing Exchange org, what the servers are capable of handling, size of the emails you are talking about sending, etc. it isn't easy to answer this.  You may not even notice anything, or it may bring everything to a crawl.

For instance, if all the users are local to the Exchange server, could be no big deal.  If you have 300 at a remote office over a T1, then you'll be saturating that link for a while if the emails are large (assuming no QoS).

By default Exchange doesn't care about "priority" flags.  You can enable priority queuing though.  See here for a walkthrough for Exchange 2010: http://howexchangeworks.com/2011/05/enabling-priority-queuing-in-exchange.html

Personally though...I've yet to see a report that ALL employees care to see unless it included something about bonuses for everyone.  You might be better off hosting the report on something like Sharepoint, intranet, etc. and sending out instructions on how the employees can visit that report when they want, get alerts when it changes, etc.  Otherwise, you might end up finding out that the emails you are sending out are simply being deleted, wasting time and resources.

Comment: +1 for the last comment. This smells like spam. Most people will not care about this at all - use sql server reporting services for that. Do not send it to everyone. I really have to wonder what may be in such a report everyone in a 1000 people company cares about. Total bonus report etc. is about everything i can imagine, too.

Comment: It IS about bonus. That's why they will check it. And why it has to be sent, it is a company policy, it has legal issues so it must be sent.

Comment: You can use Jestress: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36849 if you want.  Really though, we don't know your environment, so we can't speak as to what kind of impact it would have.  Like Grant says in the other answer, you might be over thinking it.  How big is an individual email?  BTW, if they DO include bonus information, it may be best to only send a URL link to a secure site they have to login to.

Comment: @TheCleaner I do not have the specifications, but I guess the exchange server in the company is hosted in a pretty decent way to serve the 30k employees. I will try to get the specifications later and update the question.

Comment: @HaLaBi - One thing to consider, and something I always recommend, is to have the "normal" windows SMTP service running on your the server that is hosting the app that generates the reports, and the app should submit mails to the local MTA, which is configured to relay messages to your Exchange org. This way, the application can queue up mails as fast as it's able, and then the MTA can be set to only deliver mails as fast as you want, as to not swamp the Exchange server.

Comment: I'm actually surprised.  Surprised because you seem to be saying you aren't responsible for the mail server, just the app, but are concerned how the mail server will handle it.  Most devs would simply let the email admin worry about that post go-live.  Kudos to you, but unfortunately it's all pretty subjective at this point without knowing what the server(s) can or can't handle and how large the individual emails will be.

Comment: @TheCleaner the application is not hosted by the IT, it is a department application, and I do not want to cause any problem with the IT geeks. so I am trying to be as low profile as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would send an identical e-mail, in a single operation, to a mailing alias that expands to all those employees for whom the report is generated.

The contents of that e-mail would be some instructions along with a URL for retrieving the report.

The URL takes everyone to a page where they authenticate (if they aren't already) and then are taken to their individualized report based on their user ID.

The report viewing page can let them save it as a PDF, or forward it to an e-mail address, etc.